# google firebase how to authentication server with php

Tags: php, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm making an app with new launched google firebase service.

My backend service written with PHP, but I do not find how to authenticate my server with firebase database.

Google provide java/node.js sdk to auth server like following:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges

```
// Initialize the app with a custom auth variable, limiting the server's access
Map<String, Object> auth = new HashMap<String, Object>();
auth.put("uid", "my-service-worker");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com")
.setServiceAccount(new     FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"))
.setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(auth)
.build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

// The app only has access as defined in the Security Rules
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
.getInstance()
.getReference("/some_resource");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String res = dataSnapshot.getValue();
    System.out.println(res);
}
});
```

In REST section, no auth method mentioned, and I found a php helper libary :
https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

The auth sample code is to use url and token

```
const DEFAULT_URL = 'https://kidsplace.firebaseio.com/';
const DEFAULT_TOKEN = 'MqL0c8tKCtheLSYcygYNtGhU8Z2hULOFs9OKPdEp';
const DEFAULT_PATH = '/firebase/example';

$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);


$dateTime = new DateTime();
$firebase->set(DEFAULT_PATH . '/' . $dateTime->format('c'), $test);
```

Is this work for new google firebase service ?  How can I auth my server with the "serviceAccountCredentials.json" file created in google developer console? thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get a token to authenticate against the PHP library?